how to fix it , I'm doing App chat . Sorry if the language is difficult to read, I'm Thai
const __direname=path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
                                                   ^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module


Node needs to be told that it's working with ESM, rather than the legacy CJS
